# Need help finishing a program

Tags: python, data-structures

I need some help finishing this code. I don't expect you to give me the full answer, I just need some hint about the 2 functions. thanks

```
class Trie(object):
    """A Trie of TrieNodes. Trie has the following attributes:
     -- _root: a TrieNode; the root of this Trie.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty Trie."""

        self._root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, word, data):
        """Insert the string 'word' with data 'data' into this Trie.

        -- word: the string with which the newly inserted 'data' will
           be associated.
        -- data: the data which will be stored in the TrieNode
           associated with the string 'word'.

        If there is a TrieNode associated with the word 'word' in this
        Trie, then _data of this TrieNode is updated to 'data'. Otherwise,
        enough new TrieNodes are created and inserted into this Trie, to
        create a TrieNode associated with 'word'.
        """

        raise Exception, "Implement me!"

    def find_node(self, word):
        """Return the TrieNode that corresponds to the string 'word'
        in this Trie. Return None if there is no such TrieNode in this
        Trie.
        -- word: a string; the TrieNode that corresponds to 'word'
        (if it exists) is returned.
        """

        raise Exception, "Implement me!"
```

Comment: Tagging as [homework](http://www.cdf.utoronto.ca/~csc148h/winter/assignments/a3/trie.py).

Comment: He hints are in the docstring, what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I hope this isn't homework... are they really teaching data structures in Python?

Comment: @Joe: What would be so terrifying about that?

Comment: @delnan - nothing in particular, but it just feels a little absurd. A trie node in C is something like an array of pointers, but in Python is something like a dictionary of references. The reason that structures like tries exist is to make languages like Python, and structures like dictionaries, possible. I know it's only a teaching exercise, but what's the point of teaching data structures if students are not likely going to be able to use them in that form? Better to teach Tries in C. IMHO.

Comment: @Joe: Tries in particular can actually be useful, in Python as in every other language, for some kinds of fuzzy string matching (which the hashtable-based builtin `dict` can't provide!). Yes, most students will never implement many of those general data structures for serious use - but that's the case for all languages. Yes, even for C. You do inevitably build some specialized data structure though.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, I've built tries for string matching too. Just ... not in Python. I take your point.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a hint, take a look at [Wikipedia's entry for the trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301407/need-help-finishing-a-program), which tells you everything you need to know about how tries work.

Okay, here's another hint:  every node of the trie will contain a dictionary whose keys are characters and whose values are trie nodes.  The `insert` method will look at `word[0]`, find or create the node for that character, and then, if `len(word)` is greater than 1, do something with `word[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

If Robert's hints aren't enough, here is a minimal implementation of a Trie with the two functions that you were having trouble with.

```
class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self, char='', data=None):
        self.children = []
        self.char = char
        self.data = data

    def get_child(self, char):
        for child in self.children:
            if child.char == char:
                return child

    def insert(self, key, data, node=None):
        if node is None:
            node = self
        if len(key) == 0:
            #key found
            node.data = data
            return node.data
        else:
            child = node.get_child(key[0])
            if child is None:
                child = Trie(key[0])
                node.children.append(child)
                return self.insert(key[1:], data, child)
            return self.insert(key[1:], data, child)

    def find(self, key, node=None):
        if node is None:
            node = self
        if len(key) == 0:
            #key found
            return node.data
        else:
            child = node.get_child(key[0])

            if child is None:
                return None
            return self.find(key[1:], child)

>>> tree = Trie()
>>> tree.insert('t', 't data')
>>> tree.insert('tr', 'tr data')
>>> print tree.find('t'), tree.find('tr')
t data tr data
```